# Time Machine config (Late 2020) - need for Avahi? Using Docker as best practices?

Tags: networking, samba, apple, avahi, mdns

I'm about to upgrade the hardware in my server that is using a SAMBA/Avahi configuration to act as a network Time Machine backup for my Macs.   Just perusing the different documentation - it seems that the latest versions of SAMBA in Ubuntu broadcasts itself using mDNS.   Is Avahi thus still necessary, ie. does it do some mDNS/DNS-SD magic that SAMBA is unable to do itself for Time Machine?

I also ought to play around with setting things up via Docker for portability reasons...but I am a total Docker novice at the moment....

Answer (score 1):

Fot the avahi part that is an interesting question. I didn't know so I ran some tests:

First I wanted to see if avahi was a compiled option in samba:

```
~$ smbd -b | grep AVAHI
   HAVE_AVAHI_CLIENT_CLIENT_H
   HAVE_AVAHI_COMMON_WATCH_H
   HAVE_AVAHI_CLIENT_NEW
   HAVE_AVAHI_STRERROR
   HAVE_LIBAVAHI_CLIENT
   HAVE_LIBAVAHI_COMMON
   WITH_AVAHI_SUPPORT
```

It would appear that it is.

So I figured the only way to confirm this is to disable avahi-daemon.

*Note: You can't just "stop" or "disable" the service because cups-browse will just start it up again so you have to mask it:*

```
sudo systemctl mask avahi-daeemon
```

Then I had to reboot the server.

I could no longer "see" the ubuntu server from the Mac or connect to it with a smb://hostname.local ...

Looks like avahi is a requirement to me.

*Note: I needed to "unmask" the service and restart it to restore things:*

```
sudo systemctl unmask avahi-daemon
sudo systemctl restart avahi-daemon
```